# What does in within a code block after a function call do in Swift?

Tags: swift, function

I've tried to make a minimal example, please forgive me if there are any mistakes/issues:

```
func foo(numberOfItems: Int) {
    let myArray = Array()
    let count = 0
    
    for _ in 0..<(numberOfItems) {
        let item = count
        myArray.append(item)
        count += 1
    }
}

func bar() -> Int {
    foo(numberOfItems: 5) { (item) in // what does this do?
        return item
    }
}
```

In function `bar`, what does the code block with the `in` keyword after the call to `foo` do? Or if this specific example doesn't make sense, in what circumstances would something like this be used?

Comment: That's a closure. Please read the Swift Language Guide, and it'll solve all the "what is this syntax" questions you'll inevitably run into

Comment: A [mcve] should at least *compile* ...

Comment: Search on, 'Passing Closures as a function parameter' you will get more idea.

Comment: [Closures](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html) from [The Swift Programming Language](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

'The start of the closure’s body is introduced by the in keyword. This keyword indicates that the definition of the closure’s parameters and return type has finished, and the body of the closure is about to begin.'

For more information on closures you can go through this article : https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html

Answer (score 0):

To quote Apple's Swift iBook:

> Closure Expression Syntax:
>
> Closure expression syntax has the following
> general form:
>
> ```
> { (parameters) -> return type in
>     statements
> }
> ```

And

> The start of the closure’s body is introduced by the in keyword. This
> keyword indicates that the definition of the closure’s parameters and
> return type has finished, and the body of the closure is about to
> begin.

Your example doesn't make sense since the foo function doesn't take a closure.

---

Excerpt From: Apple Inc. “The Swift Programming Language (Swift 5.1).” Apple Books. https://books.apple.com/us/book/the-swift-programming-language-swift-5-2/id881256329

Excerpt From: Apple Inc. “The Swift Programming Language (Swift 5.1).” Apple Books. https://books.apple.com/us/book/the-swift-programming-language-swift-5-2/id881256329

Answer (score 0):

That is a closure used as a callback in swift. Please refer to the below link for more detail about the syntax and usage.

https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html

Answer (score 0):

The code you have given above is incorrect syntax.
What you are describing is a closure. This closure "block" will be executed (and whatever code is in it) after the function call completes (there are exceptions to this as some higher order functions use completion handlers that run asynchronous) "Closures are often called asynchronously, but they don't have to be. Higher order functions like map, filter, sorted, etc use closures that are called synchronously. - DuncanC".

This is particularly useful when working with swift, it allows you execute specific code at a specific time when you need it to happen.

A simple example would be below where you have an animation and some code to do stuff, when thats finished , inside the completion block or "closure" you can set parameters (if you wish) to then return when that block finishes. Below i have added "_" this means no parameters.

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: { _ in
    //execute your code here 
}, completion: { _ in 
    //THis is also a closure where you can execute code after the animation is finished. 
})
```

Another example:

Function api call

```
func foo(x: String, completion:(Bool?, String?)->Void){
    //do your code here 
    //when code is finished assuming it is successful call completion handler
    //usually there is a condition to meet so that if the api call fails the completion handler will be completionHandler(false, "failure")
    completionHandler(true, "success")
}
```

Then when you want to use this function below like so...

```
    foo(x: "test", completionHandler: {result, response in
        if result == true {
            print("success")
            //do extra stuff here
        } else {
            print("Failure")
            //do extra stuff here
        }
    })
```

The "response" and "result" variables declared are inferred types of the completion handler in this case (Bool?, String?)
These variables could be called anything but their types are inferred.

Hope this helps

Comment: You said "This closure "block" will be executed (and whatever code is in it) after the function call completes". Closures are **often** called asynchronously, but they don't have to be. Higher order functions like map, filter, sorted, etc use closures that are called synchronously.

Comment: @DuncanC this is good to know.. In this context though with simple functions . this still holds true. I will update answer to include your comment